# Create a new list and add data using checkboxes

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a list that stores the selected elements. The way it goes is that you give the list a name and then you select which elements you want to add to the list. First, I am creating a list with a name. Then the created list gets an auto increment primary key. I need to use listPK primary key to add the elements to the right list. My problem is that I cannot get the value out of $listRes. But if I hard code the value. For instance give $listRes = 1. It work if there is a list with primary key 1. However, I need this to get the primary key value from the recently created list. Therefore I try this:

```
$listPK = "SELECT listPK from list WHERE name = '$name';";
$listRes = mysql_query($listPK);
```

I can’t get it right. I would appreciate any hints, tips or any thoughts on how to approach this.

[image: table]

I have three tables.
[image]

**This is my code so far:**

```
if (isset($_POST['CreateList'])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO list (`name`) VALUES ('$name);");
}

    $listPK = "SELECT listPK from list WHERE name = '$name';";
    $listRes = mysql_query($listPK);

    //It is working creating a new list, but it is not working listing out the primary key afterwards. 

    foreach ($_POST['addUser'] as $check) {
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO inList (`user`, `list`) VALUES ('$check', '$listRes');");
    }
```

Comment: I can't fully understand what your problem is. Could you please elaborate your question?

Comment: Well, theres an error on `"SELECT listPK from liste WHERE name = '$name);"`, it should be `"SELECT listPK from liste WHERE name = '$name'";`

Comment: I get the error Resource id #9 when I try to echo $listRes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well First

```
$listPK = "SELECT listPK from liste WHERE name = '$name';";
```

should be like

```
$listPK = "SELECT listPK from List WHERE name = '$name'";
```

like rawk Said second

you are Selecting from `liste` but your table name in diagram is `List` with capital `L`
check that

and still not then Debugg it like `echo` $listPK

EDIT

```
$listPK = "SELECT listPK from list WHERE name = '$name';";
    $listRes = mysql_query($listPK);
```

problem is that you are not taking primary key values in your $listRes like you said you are getting resource #19 something

you need to take value of primary u need to do something like this

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($listRes))
{
foreach ($_POST['addUser'] as $check) {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO inList (`user`, `list`) VALUES ('$check', '$row['listPK']');");
}
}
```

but i do like to say that if you are doing a project for your ownself then shift to mysqli or PDO

try this and accept the question if you find this useful :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When I am doing this, I get (Resource id #9).

Comment: It is working creating a new list, but it is not working listing out the primary key afterwards.

Comment: check now may b it helps you

Comment: Found this very useful. Thank you very much for moving me in the right direction. Thanks again. :-)